# HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error:Error creating bean with name 'HomeController': Lookup method resolution failed

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have some problems when trying to use @HttpSession in Spring MVC Controller. I want to cut the first letter of an email from login page to home page with session. To avoid session being null when loading first home page when loaded I used if condition but it gives this error:
Error creating bean with name 'HomeController': Lookup method resolution failed

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping
    @Transactional
    public String Default(@SessionAttribute("email") String email,ModelMap modelMap,HttpSession httpSession) {
        if(httpSession.getAttribute("email") != null) {
            String email =(String) httpSession.getAttribute("email");
            String chacracter = email.substring(0, 1);
            modelMap.addAttribute("chacracter ", chacracter );
        }
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're duplicating the `email` variable, so that code shouldn't even compile.